# Homebrew install python release candidate version

Tags: python, homebrew, osx-mavericks

On mac os, I just updated to Maverick and  now when I try to run a script with zbar for example, I get an error : `Segmentation fault: 11`

I see on [python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/) :

> "Python 2.7.6 release candidate 1 was released on October 26, 2013.
>   This is a 2.7 series bugfix release. Most importantly, it resolves an
>   issue that caused the interactive prompt to crash on OS X 10.9. It
>   also includes numerous bugfixes over 2.7.5."

Ok Awesome ! But.. I installed python with homebrew and when i do `brew install python` its already up to date (2.7.5). How can I fix that ?

(To be honest I tried to download the .dmg fron python.org and then installed it and that becomes a mess mixing versions... So I cleaned everything and now I would like to know what is the real thing to do.)

Comment: Hold on, before you do anything. It is very, very unlikely that the #18458 crash has anything to do with your scripts segfaulting. It's _only_ the interactive interpreter's use of `libedit` that's a problem. And if it is your crash, I'm pretty sure that just installing real `readline` (`sudo easy_install readline`) will make it irrelevant, as well as giving you a better interactive experience.

Comment: I'm guessing that you upgraded to 10.9, which means you upgraded from Apple's old Python 2.7.2 to their new 2.7.5, but you didn't reinstall any Python binary extensions that you'd built and installed against the old 2.7.2. If so, _that_ is more likely to be your problem.

Comment: On top of that, it sounds like you already have at least one extra Python 2.7, a Homebrew 2.7.5, in addition to the Apple system Python 2.7.5. (`brew install python` wouldn't give you that message otherwise.) Do you actually need that for some reason? If not, get rid of it (or just `brew unlink` it, so it's still there if you want it back but doesn't get in the way).

Comment: So I actually fixed the issue.. for maverick but as you said it had nothing to do with it. It seems that's a zbar issue..
I lost almost one afternoon trying to fix all those issues.. But I would need too much time to understand what's really happening.. 

I went back to my old friend java and now everything is going smoothly. Someday when ill have more time, ill give python a new try. 

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

At the time you wrote the question, Python 2.7.6 was not yet released.  The text you quoted talks about a release candidate, which is not the final release.  In the meantime, 2.7.6 has been released (today, at the time I write this), but Homebrew has not packaged it yet.  Just give it some time.

It's unlikely that your crash has to do with this, though.  At least you haven't shown any information to support this suspicion.  Most people have not had problems with homebrewed Python after upgrading to Mavericks.